# How to activate full screen flag in vimeo, youtube video in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, vimeo

I have an iframe which contains vimeo video How I can activate full screen flag in that video

Here is the HTML of iframe which contains video.

```
<iframe width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/155984146?color=ececec&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Use

```
 allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen"
```

under your iframe tag then it will becom like this

```
<iframe width="500" height="281" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/155984146" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen"> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi you have to allow full screen on your iframe.

just add webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen to your iframe

```
<iframe width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/155984146?color=ececec&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0;"></iframe>
```

Comment: That worked for me, thanks! Note: if you are using CodeSandbox, make sure to open in a new Window for testing, because I think the browser to the right is also in iframe and hence it won't work in CodeSandbox editor's browser.